# curl hangs and does nothing

Tags: 18.04, curl

I have specific domain, that can be accessed from everywhere. When I do this on other PC it works:

```
curl -v mydomain.com
```

But when I do the same from my PC it just hangs infinitely. No errors, just nothing. Also domain is resolved and it's okay, I can access it from browser also. If curl -v google.com it works!
Also in C++ CURL returns 0 HTTP response code without any errors. Why does this happens?